# Adding a column containing hist bins to a data frame

Tags: r, bins

I am new to R and am struggling to create assign a set of bins to a data frame that contains a set of numbers. Such as:

```
value
21
53
1
43
56
```

If I run `hist` then I know I can assign these values to a bin but that gives me a graphical output. How do I assign the bins to a new column in a data frame, i.e.,

```
value  class
21     20
53     50
1      0
43     40
56     50
```

Answer (score 0):

RTM, i.e. the help page. `hist` has an argument that suppresses plotting. In any case it returns a list with values for the breaks and the counts.

```
str(hist(dfrm$values))   #  same list as you find in the Values section of ?hist

> dfrm$grp <- cut(dfrm$value, breaks=hist(dfrm$value)$breaks)

> dfrm
  value     grp
1    21 (20,30]
2    53 (50,60]
3     1  (0,10]
4    43 (40,50]
5    56 (50,60]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have learned something about hist but I still don't get how to create the new (combined) data frame. When I say I am an R newbie I really mean it literally!

Comment: It's a bit of a PITA to recreate data objects. It's probably not as error prone in this particular instance, but it is rather error prone in general.  Why not read how to use dput() to communicate efficiently and unambiguously, rather than implicitly expecting responders to reconstruct data objects?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `df`, something like this should work.

```
bins <- c(0, 10, 20)

df$class <- findInterval(value, bins)
```